# почему оптимизатор запросов игнорирует индексированное представление

Tags: sql-server

Есть запрос, который возвращает некоторую агрегацию по таблице заказов:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(InvoiceDate) AS InvoiceYear,
    COUNT(InvoiceID) AS InvoiceCount
FROM Sales.Invoices
GROUP BY YEAR(InvoiceDate);
```

..и наблюдаю следующий план запроса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я бы хотел избавиться от тяжелого оператора Hash Match с помощью индексированного представления

```
CREATE or alter VIEW Sales.vSalesByYear
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
    YEAR(InvoiceDate) AS InvoiceYear,
    COUNT_BIG(*) AS InvoiceCount
FROM Sales.Invoices
GROUP BY YEAR(InvoiceDate);
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_vSalesByYear
    ON Sales.vSalesByYear (InvoiceYear);
GO
```

Почему при повторном выполнении запроса, план не меняется, и оптимизатор никак не хочет ссылаться на индексированное представление, ведь ему так легче будет?

Если напрямую обращаться к представлению, то план, который я хочу увидеть, появляется только после применения хинта (noexpand):

```
select 
  InvoiceYear
, InvoiceCount from Sales.vSalesByYear with (noexpand)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что показывает `SELECT @@VERSION`, какая версия и редакция? То, чего вы добиваетесь (т.н. _view matching_), доступно не во всех версиях и редакциях. Вдобавок, позволяет ли _NULL_-ы столбец `InvoiceID` в таблице `Sales.Invoices`?

Comment: мб из-за того, что COUNT(Column) и COUNT(*) - это в общем случае не одно и то же? Замените в запросе InvoiceID на * и проверьте результат.

Comment: Спасибо, проблему решил. view matching работает только в enterprise версии

Answer (score -1):

Индексированное представление - это представление. Если вы его не используете, то и индекс тоже использоваться не будет. Если вы хотите чтоб в запросе к таблице использовался индекс, то индексируйте таблицу. А со временим набрав статистики оптимизатор сделает верное решение

Comment: не согласен с Вами, оптимизатор может использовать индексы вьюшки для физических таблиц